# Save tkinter string for use after mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to have my script run and then save a userinput string after the mainloop ends, as i then want to call it later on in the same python script (but not in tkinter).
The strings i want to save are the location(w) and mac.
Please see script below and let me know if you have any ideas!

```
from Tkinter import *

OPTIONS = [
"Choose Site",
"Site1",
"Site2",
"Site3",
] 


master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

mac= Entry (master, text= "Enter Mac Address")
mac.pack()


def call_and_ok():
    print ("Location:" + variable.get())
    print ("MAC address is:" + mac.get())

button_1 = Button(master, text="RUN", command=call_and_ok,)
button_1.pack()


mainloop()


location = variable.get()
macstored = mac.get()

print (location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tkinter's [protocol handlers](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111215134/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols) to define your own handler for deletion of the window by using `master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)`. In this handler, you can make sure to get the current values and store them (in global variables) before actually destroying the mainloop.

Place this before your call to `mainloop()`

```
location = ''
macstored = ''

def callback():
    global location
    global macstored
    location = variable.get()
    macstored = mac.get()
    master.destroy()

master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)
```

Comment: That works perfectl. Thanks for the super quick answer!

Comment: No problem. Do keep in mind that saving the contents of the widgets when destroying the window might not be the most intuitive for a user. You may consider adding the lines in `callback` to the command that's behind the button press so a press of the button saves the entries and destroys the window.

Comment: will look into that, this is a rough draft of the script but the functions i want to work are at least working now :)